# why when i resize an image in php my new image has a big size in relation to the first image?

Tags: php, html

I have this image 0.jpg and his dimension is 800*534 and size is 44, 8 ko.
When i use this function:

```
function image_reduce($image, $desired_width, $target_file, $extension, $quality = 100){

        ini_set('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', 1);
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);

        if($source_image){
            $width = imagesx($source_image);
            $height = imagesy($source_image);

            if($width > $desired_width){
                $desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));
                $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

                imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);
                imagejpeg($virtual_image, $target_file, $quality);
            }
            else imagejpeg($source_image, $target_file, $quality);
            imagedestroy($source_image);

            return false;
    }
    else return true;
}
```

to reduce the image i obtain a new image who have the dimension 600*400 but the size is 140ko.

Everybody can help me?

Comment: Chances are the quality setting of the input image is not 100. If you want a smaller output image, use a lower quality setting. I usually stick with 80 since there's usually little noticeable compression artifacts and decent compression. 90 if you're a stickler, and anyone using 100 should be using a lossless format and not JPEG in the first place.

Comment: It's possible to detect the quality of image in php?

Comment: 100 is pretty rare with JPGs. When you convert one JPG to another one, the quality of the original doesn't matter. It's always just an "original image". So when you save an image of heavy compression to an image with less compression, the file size is going to be bigger.

Comment: @BigWatanga just google your question.